# Custom Error Logging in MSAL.js library is not working

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, error-logging, msal.js

We want to log the custom errors which are thrown by MSAL.js library into our Database but somehow we are not able to log it.

The errors are thrown into console. For e.g.
[image]

What I understood so far MSAL.js library is throwing the error but the bluebird is eating that error and just showing into the console.

Is there a way so that we can get those errors which are thrown by the MSAL into any other library or the custom code ( where I will have window.onerror event and I will use this to send the error to DB)  so that we can log it into our Database for tracking purpose.

I have used js these files in this order.

[image]

I have tried loggging the error into

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) { ... };
```

in custom js file but its not working

Answer (score 0):

`ClientAuthError`: which denotes an issue with Client authentication. Most errors that come from the library will be `ClientAuthErrors`. These errors result from things like calling a login method when login is already in progress, the user cancels the login, etc.,

Similar type of issue with fix see [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2452)

Refer  [msal error handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-error-handling-js)  & [msal-logging-js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-logging-js)